# Robust task scheduler with task restart on failure

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduler

I need some sort of a task scheduler, which will schedule execution of a task (once) and monitor if the task is still 'alive', so if some uncaught exception will happen (like IOexception, or database connection failure) - the scheduler will re-start the task from scratch.

I don't want to catch Throwable in the while(true) loop, just want to let it fail.

Ideally, new thread should be created.

Is there something ready-to-use? Its straightforward to implement this kind of scheduler with ThreadFactory, still not sure if I should re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

[Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is a very good scheduler; [here is some retry-on-failure code](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2010/12/automatically-retry-failed-jobs-in.html)

Comment: well, it's too heavy for that simple task. It's like using Spring MVC for single-page website.

Comment: Agreed - I wasn't sure if this was your only scheduling task, or if you had additional jobs that might warrant using a full blown scheduler

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    };
    for (;;) {
        ScheduledExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        ScheduledFuture<?> f = ex.schedule(task, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        try {
            f.get();
            break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            f.cancel(true); 
            break;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // process exception
        } finally {
            ex.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

If an exception happens during task execution f.get() throws an ExecutionException, you can process it and reschedule

Comment: I need to schedule task only once, after some fixed delay.